# how to make a stage run only once in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, automation, cicd

I have Jenkins pipeline and I want to run a stage only once and it will skip the next stages. how do I achieve this with this pipeline?

let me explain with tis example...

i want B to run only once if it succeded C will not run.

```
pipeline{
  agent none

stages{

 stage("A"){

  steps{
           "some code"  

    }

   }
 stage("B"){

  steps{
           "some code"  
    }

   }
 stage("c"){

  steps{
         "some code" 
    }

   }
 }

}
```

Comment: Stages already run only once

Comment: What did you try to not run step C if B is ok?

Comment: @GaëlJ Yeah run only once for each build, but i want it to run 1 time and not in the next builds

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible and not really a use case for Jenkins pipeline, why not run it manually if it has to run only once ever?

Comment: @GaëlJ this build is going to run in multi able platforms,, i don't want to do it manually